# Why is my ruby test not finding visit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, minitest

I am using minitest and rails and capybara and the following test gives me this error...

```
    undefined method `visit' for #<Page:0x007f8bf3697630>
    STDERR:
    Exception `NoMethodError' at /Users/trace/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@application.1/gems/activemodel-3.1.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:385:in `method_missing'
    /Users/trace/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@application.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:60:in `method_missing'
    /Users/trace/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@application.1/gems/capybara-2.0.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
    test/support/utilities.rb:2:in `sign_in_user'
    test/integration/pages_intergration_test.rb:12:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /Users/trace/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@application.1/gems/mocha-0.9.12/lib/mocha/integration/mini_test/version_201_to_202.rb:27:in `run'
```

Here is my in file `test/integration/pages_intergration_test.rb`

```
require "minitest_helper"

describe "Pages integration" do
  let(:page) { FactoryGirl.create(:page }

  describe "Page Management tool" do

    describe "Visiting a page" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
      it "Should see the welcome message" do
        sign_in_user(admin_user)
        should have_content("Welcome")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and my file `test/support/utilities.rb`

```
def sign_in_user(user)
  visit root_path
  fill_in "EMAIL ADDRESS",    with: user.email
  fill_in "PASSWORD",         with: user.password
  click_button "SIGN IN"
end
```

and here is my minitest.rb ...just in case i might of done something wrong here

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

require "minitest/autorun"
require "minitest/rails"
require "minitest/rails/capybara"
require "active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown"
require 'turn'

require 'factory_girl'

Dir[Rails.root.join("test/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

Dir.glob(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/factories/*").each do |factory|
  require factory
end

require 'database_cleaner'
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

class MiniTest::Rails::ActiveSupport::TestCase
  before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  after :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end

class IntegrationTest < MiniTest::Spec
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include Capybara::DSL

  register_spec_type(/integration$/, self)

  before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  after :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
    Capybara.use_default_driver
  end
end

class HelperTest < MiniTest::Spec
  include ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown
  include ActionView::TestCase::Behavior
  register_spec_type(/Helper$/, self)

  before :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  after :each do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

any ideas on what is the problem...

Answer (score 2):

The most recent version of Capybara (2.0 branch) has changes that need to be taken into consideration. Here's the relevant section from the [changelog](https://gist.github.com/3980553) (with the relevant passage bolded):

> Notably, we changed the :type that Capybara assumes your specs run
>   under in RSpec to :feature (previously it was :request). The latest
>   release of spec/features. Alternatively you can use the Capybara
>   Feature DSL (feature instead of describe), which should work without
>   any additional tweaking. **If you see errors like undefined method
>   visit, then you're probably encountering this issue.** If you're
>   including modules into :request specs, you will probably need to
>   change that to :feature.

So, it's possible changing the `describe` to `feature` could correct the issue.

Comment: FWIW, minitest-rails-capybara doesn't support the feature DSL yet. It will, but doesn't today.